# p:captcha throws "HTTP Status 500 - Connection timed out: connect"

Tags: jsf, primefaces, captcha, connection-timeout

I'm using PrimeFaces `<p:captcha>` component. It works fine on local machine but when I deploy project to the server it throws "HTTP Status 500 - Connection timed out: connect".

Here is my xhtml code:

```
<f:facet name="header">
    <p:messages/>    
    <p:captcha label="Captcha" language="ru"
               validatorMessage="Вы робот! Попробуйте пройти проверку еще раз."
               rendered="#{loginBean.wrongLogins >= loginBean.wrongLoginsAvailable}"/>
</f:facet>
<h:panelGroup>
    <h:commandButton id="login"
                     ajax="false"
                     type="submit"
                     actionListener="#{loginBean.doLogin}"
                     value="#{login['login']}"
                     >
    </h:commandButton>
</h:panelGroup>
```

UPDATE!!!
There's important thing I forgot to say: captcha displays fine and show success checkbox when you click on it. Timeout error happens when I click "login" button and before my own user verification.

Comment: if it is a stacktrace IN the captcha (you don't post that so we can only guess) then check the network connection from **your server** to the google captcha server. Should be simple to deduce this

Comment: Google server pings fine (from a terminal at least). Stacktrace (not full):
javax.faces.FacesException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
 at org.primefaces.component.captcha.Captcha.validateValue(Captcha.java:157)
 at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:982)
 at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1248)
 at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)

Comment: Also we have connections to other servers (such as yandex.ru) that works fine. And captcha worked as it would few month ago. Fine, I mean.

Comment: ping != a real connection

Comment: Ok, I already said that connection to other services is fine. And captcha worked normally at least month ago. How can I test the connection of my application to google without deploying any code?

Comment: Ok,ok… Server A != Server B. Look at the url of were the connection should go to and try that on the terminal

Comment: Ok, I realize that problem in our production server. When I tried to pass captcha in browser (launched on server) through localhost it fails with same exception (but when I did the same thing on test server it worked fine).

Comment: Like I said in my first comment ;-)

Comment: Ant ideas? Why can this happen? Tomcat settings?

Comment: covernment interference? Company Firewall that has been changed? Midgets?

Comment: It works fine on test server (when I run browser on it). The difference between them is only tomcat port: 8083 on test and 80 on production.

Comment: That is INCOMING on the server, not outgoing...

Comment: So.. If it's incoming - (error happens on captcha validation) - what the problem it could be? I still have no any idea, cause firewall is not enabled at all, antivirus silent as night, but captcha fails (at two different pages).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in captcha but in proxy server. Outcoming request was locked so google couldn't response my captcha. After configuring auth on proxy from java application it works fine!